# localSearch in semantic UI mutli select dropwdown list doesnt work with Remote Content

Tags: angularjs, semantic-ui

Here i am trying to get Unit type from db(using asp.net mvc core)& in the view trying to bind to multi select drop down list.
html code of a dropdown,

```
<div name="dropdown" class="ui  fluid multiple search selection dropdown">
  <input class="search" tabindex="0">
  <div class="default text">Unit type filter</div><i class="dropdown icon"></i>
  <input type="hidden" name="temporary">
  <div class="menu"></div>
</div>
$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown({
  apiSettings: {
    url: 'api/projectSearch/GetUnitType'
  },
  maxSelections: 3,
  localSearch: true,
  saveRemoteData: false,
  debug: true,
  fullTextSearch: true
});
```

The result i get from an API is,

```
{
  "results": [{
    "name": "FCC",
    "value": "FCC",
    "text": "FCC"
  }, {
    "name": "Utilities",
    "value": "Utilities",
    "text": "Utilities"
  }, {
    "name": "Visbreaking",
    "value": "Visbreaking",
    "text": "Visbreaking"
  }],
  "success": true
}
```

Am able to view the list & select multiple unit types from the dropdown. but local search with these items doesnt work. if i type in the dropdown i don't get the intellisense.  i have tried with a basic dropdown also thinking that above dropdown may have some issues,


But still no luck.  Note that am using angular 1.6.1 & am not writing any controller code to get unit types.basically apiSettings gets me the data.
where am i missing? please correct me.

Comment: try changing `localSearch: false,` to `localSearch: true,`

Comment: Can you see the list of options for selection

Comment: yes am able to see the list, choose multiple items also able to delete selected items. but local search for intelisense doesn't work here. I have also set localSearch to true, still no luck

Comment: any help on this?